# Matlab equivalent to calling inside static class

Tags: oop, class, matlab, static

Confer the following code:

```
classdef highLowGame
    methods(Static)
        function [wonAmount, noGuesses] = run(gambledAmount)
            noGuesses = 'something';
            wonAmount = highLowGame.getPayout(gambledAmount, noGuesses); % <---
        end
        function wonAmount = getPayout(gambledAmount, noGuesses)
            wonAmount = 'something';
        end
    end
end
```

Is there a way to call a static method of the same class (inside a static) method without having to write the class name? Something like "self.getPayout(...)" - in case the class turns out to get to 500 lines and I want to rename it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, "no" with a "but".  In general, you can only specify the static method with the class name.  However, you can fake your way around the restriction since MATLAB has feval:

```
classdef testStatic

    methods (Static)
        function p = getPi()  %this is a static method
            p = 3.14;
        end
    end

    methods
        function self = testStatic()

            testStatic.getPi  %these are all equivalent
            feval(sprintf('%s.getPi',class(self)))
            feval(sprintf('%s.getPi',mfilename('class')))
        end
    end
end
```

Here, class(self) and mfilename both evaluate to 'testStatic', so the functions above end up evaluating 'testStatic.getPi'.

Or, alteratively, you can write a non-static method, self.callStatic; then always use that.  Inside that, just call testStatic.getPi.  Then you'll only need to change that one line.

Comment: that should be `mfilename('class')` in case you had a separate function in a @-folder defined class.

Comment: still I would rather just write the name of the class explicitly, and rely on a good editor to do find/replace in case I need to refactor.. A class name is not something you expect to change often.

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer to your question directly, but it's worth noting that you can also put "local functions" after the end of your `classdef` block in your `class.m` file, and these behave like private static methods, but you do not need to invoke them using the class name. I.e.

```
% myclass.m
classdef myclass
  methods ( Static )
    function x = foo()
      x = iMyFoo();
    end
  end
end
function x = iMyFoo()
  x = rand();
end
% end of myclass.m
```

Comment: Putting functions after the end of classdef? Interesting :)