# How do I create a class with constant properties accessible to other classes within a package folder structure?

Tags: matlab, oop, package

I have the following file structure of packages for my MatLab project:

```
RootFolder
    +CustomUiElements
        Styles.m
        ...
    ...
    +DetailView
        Controller.m
        ...
    MainApp.m
```

Within the `Controller.m` file I'm having issues accessing the class file `Styles.m` which is simply a data class with properties that are structures of properties to be used as "styles" for my ui elements:

```
classdef Styles
    %STYLES A collection of structures used to unify the styling of the
    %   application.  

    properties (Constant = true)
        FontName = 'Helvetica';
        FontSizes = struct('Title', 16, 'SubTitle', 14, 'BodyTitle', 12, 'Body', 10);
        TabSizes = struct('Title', 260, 'LrgSubTitle', 120, 'SmlSubTitle', 75);
        PaddingSizes = struct('None', 0, 'Small', 2, 'Med', 5, 'Large', 10);

        LargeTabStyle = struct('FontName', Styles.FontName, ...
            'FontSize', Styles.FontSizes.Title, 'FontWeight', 'demi', ...
            'TabSize', Styles.TabSizes.Title);

... % and so forth
```

However whenever I try to call the class property, even from the console I get the following error:

```
>> CustomUiElements.Styles.LargeTabStyle
Undefined variable "Styles" or class "Styles.FontName".
```

Since I'm not even trying to access the prop `FontName` this is leading me to believe that this is an issue with the construction of the obj of class `Styles`.  I didn't have any errors, before switching to a "non-packaged" folder structure.  How do I create a class that has Constant props and is accessible using a package folder structure.

**Edit:**

I'm able to access and use other class files within that folder (CustomUiElements).  However they have custom constructors, methods, and properties, which `Styles` only has properties that are `Constant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have "RootFolder" added on the path? Here is a quick test I did, which works just fine (I'm running R2013a):

#### root/+pkg/MyClass.m

```
classdef MyClass
    properties (Constant)
        Version = '1.0';
        Info = struct('Name','MyClass', 'Version',pkg.MyClass.Version);
    end
end
```

Now

```
>> addpath('/path/to/root')
>> pkg.MyClass.Version
ans =
1.0
>> pkg.MyClass.Info.Version
ans =
1.0
```

So I was able to even directly index into the returned structure.

Note that if you want to reference any of the constant properties inside other properties, you have to use the fully qualified name including the package name (just like we did for the "Version" property inside the structure)

Comment: Yes I have checked this.  I just copied your code into mine and created a simple class and tested it out.  It works for me as well.  I also just converted all my code to be regular properties that are instantiated upon class construction and it works that way as well.  It has to do with something in my code.

Comment: Wait!  I think I know what it is.  I'm calling `Styles.<Prop Name>` within the other props.  I think it needs to be `CustomUiElements.Styles.<Prop Name>`  I'll check and see and then let you know

Comment: I think I see the problem now; you have properties inside `Styles` that are accessing other constant properties in the same class. Unfortunately, you have to use the full qualified name with the package name as well (for example `LargeTabStyle` must be: `struct('FontName', CustomUiElements.Styles.FontName, ...)`

Comment: Ah I see you reached the same conclusion :) I remember someone asked about this issue before here on SO, let me see If I can find that question... They wanted to avoid having to hardcode the package name inside the class

Comment: if you update you answer, I'll accept.  I would keep the original as well, as some other users might come across this and not have the root folder in the path.

Comment: so I found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503209/matlab-equivalent-to-calling-inside-static-class) which is different from what I had in mind but the idea is similar: if you want to avoid having to hard-code the containing package name, you'll have to parse the output of `mfilename` to get the package name, and use `eval` to access another property. Ugly workaround if you ask me :) btw I have edited my post as requested.