# How to use private methods inside public methods in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have couple methods in Matlab class. I am accessing few of them in some of these methods but somehow, in order to call those methods, I need to place "instaceName." in start of method names. I have c# background and does not feel comfortable. In C#, different level of visibility of methods can be defined.

```
classdef SampleClass
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this class goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

properties
    result ;
end

methods
    function method1 (obj, a , b) 
       obj.result = obj.method2 (a,b) ;
    end
end
methods (Access= private)
    function y = method3 ( a , b)
        y = a + b ; 
    end  

    end   

end
```

If I define methods as static which I want to use internally in that class then will it work.
Is there a suggestion to deal this issue.

```
classdef SampleClass
    %UNTITLED2 Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        result ;
    end

    methods
        function method1 (obj, a , b) 
           obj.result = SampleClass.method2 (a,b) ;
        end      

    end

    methods (Static)
        function y = method2 ( a , b) 
            y = a + b ; 
        end      

    end

end
```

Comment: It is working. I want something simple and elegant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab equivalent to calling inside static class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503209/matlab-equivalent-to-calling-inside-static-class)

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html

Comment: oh maybe you are asking to avoid "instance" name. just put "obj" as the first input of the method, and call "obj.method2"

Comment: I want to method2 or methods3 without specifying the ClassName or Instance(obj) infront of method

Comment: @User1551892 http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html#bsbqc1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no workaround for the issue that you mention. Class method signatures must always pass the "instance" into itself:

```
function output = DoSomething(this, arg1, arg2)
```

There are several methods to call a class method (take for example the above method `DoSomething` from Class MyClass):

```
my_instance = MyClass(...);

% Call type 1
output = my_instance.DoSomething(arg1, arg2)

% Call type 2
output = DoSomething(my_instance, arg1, arg2)
```

The type 2 feels more intuitive and aligned with the function signature.

In your example, both the instance method and the static method are interchangeable because you are not using method properties. But that's not always the case: static methods cannot access the private/protected properties of the class.

Extra note: as far as I know, many OO languages do the same but behind the scenes (C++ and C# automatically add the instance argument to the method, but correct me if I am wrong). The only difference is that in Matlab you must do it explicitly.

[C++ explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322268/c-this-pointer-hidden-argument-in-function-calls).

Comment: I am not sure about about your Extra note and I want a confirmation about it. If your point is valid then I think so, I cannot call private method C# way.